# What is the efficient way of boolean value assignment in java?

Tags: java, boolean, variable-assignment

We can assign `boolean` value in three ways

```
    boolean isDone;
    isDone = true;
    isDone = Boolean.valueOf(true);
    isDone = Boolean.TRUE;
```

so which assignment is more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the first does not involve any boxing or unboxing. So on the face of it, the first would be the most efficient. However, most compilers (or just-in-time compilers, if present) are likely to optimize the other two assignments to be just as efficient.

The story would be different, of course, if `isDone` were declared to be a `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. In that case, the third assignment would be my preference.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely compiler and jit optimizer will optimize all of them anyway to the same thing, but the "best" theoretically is the first: `isDone = true;`, since it involves no [boxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).